# ⌘ Command+ C doesnt work and I cant do an "E" by holding ⇧ Shift

Tags: keyboard

I already tried:

1. Force quit Finder
2. `sudo launchctl start/stop com.apple.pboard`
3. System Preferences> Keyboard> Modifier Keys > Restore Defaults
4. System Preferences> Shortcuts> App Shortcuts> + (when I tried to write the shortcut in "Keyboard Shortcut" Command C doesnt work)

When I try to paste it's  ok, it works. The problem is to copy, the shortcut doesnt work and the edit flash doesnt work too. Its the same with Shift + e

The keys Command, Shift, C and e work separately. They dont work like shortcuts

Model: Macmini6,1

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do.  You never say.

Comment: I am trying to use command+C shortcut to copy. This shortcut doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Shift + e doesnt work too

Comment: If it used to work, sounds like a hardware issue with the keyboard. Update your question with the Mac model or keyboard you are using. Cheers

Comment: Is Command C the shortcut for Copy, as shown in the Edit menu? If it is, and the keys all work separately -- and you've rebooted -- then I would suspect a hardware problem. Have/Can you try another keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences and click on the keyboard. A panel opens with 5 tabs at the top.  Click on the Keyboard Tab and a new panel appears.

[image]

In this panel click on the button at the bottom which says "Modifier Keys". This brings up a menu on the previous panel. See image below.

[image]

you can define what the command key actually is. Make sure the command key is defined as the Command key.

Comment: I already tried. My command key is defined as the Command key.